# Find a necessary and sufficient condition on the natural number $n$ , for the equation $x^n + (2 + x)^n + (2 − x)^n = 0$ to have an integral root.

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

> Find a necessary and sufficient condition on the natural number $n,$ for the equation $$x^n + (2 + x)^n + (2 − x)^n = 0$$ to have an integral root.

I can see that $n$ cannot be even because then roots will not be real.

But I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Hint:  consider the rational root theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $P(x) = x^n + (2+x)^n + (2-x)^n$.  If $x$ is odd, then $P(x)$ is also odd. Hence any root must be even. But then we can write $x = 2y$, and we obtain an integral root of

$$Q(y):= \frac{P(2y)}{2^n}  = y^n + (1 + y)^n + (1-y)^n = 2 + \ldots + y^n,$$

where we use the fact that $n$ is odd to see the last coefficient is $1 + 1 + (-1)^n = 1$.
Now by the rational root theorem, the only solutions with $y$ an integer must have $y|2$, so $y
 \in \{-2,-1,1,2\}$. The values of the function $Q(y)$ at those points are (using again that $n$ is odd):

$$(-2)^n + (-1)^n + 3^n = 3^n - 2^n - 1,$$
$$(-1)^n + 0^n + 2^n = 2^n - 1,$$
$$1^n + 2^n + 0^n = 2^n + 1,$$
$$2^n + 3^n + (-1)^n = 3^n + 2^n - 1,$$

and none of these vanish unless $n=1$ and we are in the first case. Of course, if $n = 1$, then
 $P(x) = x+4$, so there is a solution with $x = -4$ or $y = -2$.

Answer (score 0):

Let put $ 2+x=y$ and  $x-2=z$ 
The equation becomes $ x^{n}+y^{n}=z^{n}$ 
And by the work of  wiles and taylor and ribet  this equation does not have integers solution when $ n>3 $ and 
When $n=1 $ then $ x=-4 $.

Comment: Since $n$ is odd so  $(-z)^{n} $ become $-z^{n} $

Comment: My comment was before the newest edit

Comment: Just one slight remark : There are no NONTRIVIAL integer solutions of $x^n+y^n=z^n$ for $n>3$ , so you can complete your argument by considering the case that one of $x,y,z$ is zero.

Comment: No, but you can study the handbook in "magma online calculator", maybe you find the proper command there.

Comment: Can you give the link

Comment: It is the first hit, if you enter those words. Under "documentation" in the pull-down menue, you will find the handbook.

Comment: For $n=2$ there is no (real) solution to the original equation, since at least two terms on the left hand side are greater than zero and all are greater or equal to zero as squares.